# Importing and Coding in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am new with Hadoop, I have an HR.csv  file to import into hadoop  that need to be stored/saved on HDFS and I really get confused when it comes to which folder on HDFS should I save and on my eclipse I only see DFS with funny files.

if am importing my csv file as
hadoop fs -put /source/dest
where source is the name of my input file and dest is where it will be stored in HDSF how can I write this if am running my Hadoop inside eclipse?

My other question is from my data file I have 9 columns but am interested in two columns, "left" wheather a person left the company or not but I should only use a mapper and a reducer for employees that left a company and another column is the department they worked in, if is sales or not.

Kindly assist with the codes of importing data, extracting only those two columns, mapper and reducer codes.

Thanks.

Comment: do you happen to be a windows user ?

Comment: @PeterSmith.yes

Comment: hmmm do you mind working with cmd ? or bash on Windows if you have windows 10 ? In my opinion it will be easier to develop in eclipse but run the app from the command line(besides I had this friend once who tried so hard to make it work on windows with eclipse with no success)

Comment: @PeterSmith. Ok. How should I do that.

Comment: well you reference hadoop jar libs into eclipse just like you reference any external libraries, those jars comes with the installation(I don't exactly recall what libs do you need but something like mappers or like)

Comment: you code and build the project just like any java project, Now from the command line you go to the folder of your executable jar and run `hadoop jar <yourjarfile> <your Main class name without .class> ...programargs`

Comment: by the way the part regarding `Main class name` isn't needed if the info is included in the jar's manifest(probably eclipse will do it but in case you see "could not find Main class" or something just supply the Main class name)

Comment: and ehm I'm niceman not PeterSmith :)